# How to find error when ROC is used as metric?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, metrics, roc

I need to choose a hyper parameter based on the lowest error rate. If I choose ROC as my metric then how do I find the error in ROC. Is there any delivered method in sklearn?

Answer (score 0):

Use the roc_auc score (sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score). This score is based on the area under the ROC curve and reflects on the amount of 'true positives' determined by the model. The error will be the flip-side of that score. :)

[link to sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)

Comment: I am told that I cannot use 1 - roc_auc_score as error.

Comment: @SanjeevRam who told you that? It is very context dependent. You probably can't call it simply "error" but that doesn't mean you can't use it for optimization...

Comment: What can you use? Can you provide more context to the  question you are being asked and its restrictions ? :)